# Can I uninstall Seahorse from Ubuntu 12.10 without side effects?

Tags: 12.10, password

I find Ubuntu (12.10)'s Seahorse intrusive and annoying and I would like to remove it using Ubuntu Software Center. If I do so, could it potentially cause me problems with future Ubuntu upgrades?

Comment: What is your complaint exactly about Seahorse? It is by no means intrusive, nor annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Ubuntu 12.10**

From the description of seahorse

```
apt-cache show seahorse
```

> Description-en: GNOME front end for GnuPG  Seahorse is a front end for
>   GnuPG - the GNU Privacy Guard program -  that integrates to the GNOME
>   desktop. It is a tool for secure  communications and data storage. 
>   Data encryption and digital signature  creation can easily be
>   performed through a GUI and Key Management  operations can easily be
>   carried out through an intuitive interface.

**Also when you attempt to unistall seahorse you will se that ubuntu-desktop will uninstalled.**

**But ubuntu-desktop is a metapackage that is not recommnded to unistall it**

from the description of ubuntu-desktop

```
apt-cache show ubuntu-desktop
```

> This package depends on all of the packages in the Ubuntu desktop
>   system  .  It is also used to help ensure proper upgrades, so it is
>   recommended that  it not be removed.

, so you have to install it again with this command

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

but when you attempt to install ubuntu-desktop again you will notice that **seahorse** package will be installed. 
Depends each other.
So I assume is not a good decision to remove seahorse.